# how to group a text by a number of lines

Tags: c#

i have a file like this 
i am reading the file 
 i need to group this by 5 lines from the start of file
the resulting list will have  the first of column 1, the highest of column 4 lowest of column 4 , sum of column 3

search gives me  group by   some id solutions, no solutions for grouping by a number of lines

thanks in advance

```
20170208  10:00:23           2     8.690
20170208  10:00:25           2     8.690
20170208  10:00:26        2383     8.690
20170208  10:00:26           1     8.690
20170208  10:00:26        7616     8.690
20170208  10:00:26           1     8.690
20170208  10:00:31         500     8.690
20170208  10:00:36           2     8.690
20170208  10:00:38           2     8.690
20170208  10:00:41        2000     8.690
20170208  10:00:41         250     8.690
20170208  10:00:41          25     8.680
20170208  10:00:42          25     8.680
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to ask] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? Show at least your expected result.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062.aspx) and [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358985.aspx).

Comment: sorry, i have nothing, really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupBy`(integer division trick groups by number of lines) and `First`/`Min`/`Max`/`Sum` are needed. Of course you also need to parse the strings to the real types:

```
var newLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index, fields = line.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 5)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Col1First = g.First().fields[0],
        Col4Max = g.Max(x => decimal.Parse(x.fields[3], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)),
        Col4Min = g.Min(x => decimal.Parse(x.fields[3], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)),
        Col3Sum = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x.fields[2]))
    })
    .ToList();
```